# Why does Console.Write treat character x266A differently?

Tags: c#, .net, unicode

I'm writing a console app that needs to print some atypical (for a console app) unicode characters such as musical notes, box drawing symbols, etc.

Most characters show up correctly, or show a ? if the glyph doesn't exist for whatever font the console is using, however I found one character which behaves oddly which can be demonstrated with the lines below:

```
Console.Write("ABC");
Console.Write('♪'); //This is the same as: Console.Write((char)0x266A);
Console.Write("XYZ");
```

When this is run it will print ABC then move the cursor back to the start of the line and overwrite it with XYZ. Why does this happen?

Comment: what happens if you print U+1D160?

Comment: What do you think `(char)0x266A` actually results in?  I can tell  you that a `char` cannot hold that value.

Comment: @ Ed S.  What makes you think a char can't hold that value?

Comment: @Code Monkey 
  Actually char cannot take the value 0x1D160.

Comment: All the unicode characters my app handles will always be below 0xFFFF.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The console doesn't use Uncode, so the characters has to be translated to an 8-bit code page. The `♪` character is converted to the character with code 13 (hex 0x0d), which is CR or Carrage Return.

In most code pages, for example [code page 850](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_850), the CR chararacter glyph resembles a quarter note, and the 266a character is specified as the Unicode equivalent.

However, if you write the CR character to the console, it will not display the quarter note glyph, instead it is interpreted as the control character CR which moves the cursor to the beginning of the line.

Comment: @dan04: Yes, that is more correct. I changed it to "8-bit code page" however, as that is the cruical difference here.

Answer (score 2):

`Console.Write('♪');` is considered Unicode. My guess it is it translates it to the closest ASCII character. You should be using `U+1D160` or the appropriate unicode, musical equivalent.

There are the required primitives to generate musical output in the Unicode code set (starting at U+1D100). For example, U+1D11A is a 5-line staff, U+1D158 is a closed notehead.

See http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U1D100.pdf

..then the issue becomes making sure that you have a typeface with the appropriate glyphs included (and dealing with the issues of spacing things correctly, etc.)

IF you're looking to generate printed output, you should look at [Lilypond](http://lilypond.org), which is an OSS music notation package that uses a text file format to define the musical content and then generates gorgeous output.

Comment: I think actually the standard Windows console uses a single codepage anyway, not Unicode, so it wouldn't work even if you picked a Unicode font.

Comment: Ah, I am thinking that may be the answer.

Comment: Thanks Code Monkey, my app isn't really for musical notation, just receiving a bunch of unicode symbols from another source and displaying them.